# Excel: Convert Text Date-Time Values to Readable Format and/or Excel Date Format, HL7, 16 character 14 character and 8 character text values to DT

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula

all. I'm a healthcare interface developer using HL7 formatted data. Many times I have exported data that contains dates or date-times in text format. This comes in three varieties:

- 16-character D/T: such as 20201225120000 for Dec. 25th 2020 at 12:00:00
- 14-character D/T: such as 202012251200 for Dec. 25th 2020 at 12:00
- 8-character D/T: such as 20201225 for Dec. 25th.

Multiple times I've done internet searches to find how to convert these values in Excel. This is a pain, because 16 digit timestamps are usually in Unix format. So, I find lots of answers about converting those values... but have a hard time re-finding the correct answer to this issue.

Over time, I've created a text file that contains the answers. So, in a spare moment during this pandemic, I thought I'd post the answers here. This will hopefully help other developers, and hopefully it will show up in search results for when I don't have the text file handy.

Comment: BTW: `20201225120000` is 14 digits and `202012251200` has 12.

Comment: Thanks! You're right... I do also get them will milliseconds.
I like your solution! It's going in my text file. :)

Comment: If you do not mind loosing the milliseconds, my formula will work for them also.

Answer (score 2):

This will do all three:

```
=--REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(A1&"000000",14),13,0,":"),11,0,":"),9,0," "),7,0,"-"),5,0,"-")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to handle this.

**1) Use an Excel custom format to make the values display in a readable way, without actually changing the value.**
Right click on the cell or column, then choose "Format Cells," then under "Category" choose "Custom." Paste the appropriate format listed below.

**2) Convert to a Date-Time using Excel text-handling functions.**
Insert a new column to the right of the text date-time column. Insert the Excel formula into the new column.

**3) Convert to an Excel Date-Time value by multiplying, then changing the column to Date format or a custom date-time format.**
Insert a new column to the right of the text date-time column. Insert the Excel formula into the new column.

**Here are ways for each of the three length variations.**

*16 "Digits"*
Example: 20201225120000 or 2020-12-25 12:00:00

Custom Format:

> ####-##-## ##:##:##

Formula to convert to Excel Date-Time (Change K2 to the correct cell ID)

> =DATE(LEFT(K2,4),MID(K2,5,2),MID(K2,7,2))+TIME(MID(K2,9,2),MID(K2,11,2),RIGHT(K2,2))

Multiplication to convert to Date-Time (Change K2 to the correct cell ID)

> =Sum(K2*0.000000000030752269457537)

*14 Digits*
Example: 202012251200 or 2020-12-25 12:00

Custom Format

> ####-##-## ##:##

Formula to convert to Excel Date-Time (Change K2 to your correct cell ID)

> =DATE(LEFT(K2,4),MID(K2,5,2),MID(K2,7,2))+TIME(MID(K2,9,2),RIGHT(K2,2))

Multiplication to convert to Date-Time (Change K2 to your correct cell ID)

> =Sum(K2*0.000000218676875311879)

*8-digit date*
Example: 202012251200 or 2020-12-25

Custom Format

> ####-##-##

Formula to convert to Excel Date-Time

> =DATE(LEFT(K2,4),MID(K2,5,2),RIGHT(K2,2))

Multiplication to convert to Date-Time

> =Sum(K2*0.002186750199616760000)

I hope this helps someone. If you have another option, please leave it below as alternative!